# What makes a border a good border in a webpage element?

Tags: website-design

I'm making use of borders inside my website's, just like the rest of the world. I use them to mark the actual size of the element.

My question is, what are the criteria for a border to be considered a good border in a webpage element?

Comment: Generally "good" is subjective. However, depending on the design you are creating, there might be a best practice. Is this question for a specific site with a specific design? Could you be a little more specific? In general, you don't want to have extra/unneeded design elements to your page, because it causes things to get cluttered and detracts from design. So ask yourself first, "Can I still convey what I am trying to without the use of the border?"

Comment: what @Andrew said. This question is incredibly vague!

Comment: I meant it in general, when can you say "this border is bad because of this reason"? And than point out the reason.

Comment: You are looking for a catch all reason. In the design world, there isn't really such a thing (unfortunately). There isn't a formula for "good design." A border might be an excellent design choice in one site, due to the overall design, but a horrible choice for another site. Design doesn't follow the same principals as say html markup where there are direct answers for "When should I do this?" Therefore, if you truly want an answer for a very general design question, the general answer is, "When it fits the design." And that answer is too broad to be of real help...

Comment: Does that comment help you reform your question? If not, are you okay with receiving broad answers?

Comment: Yes. I'm ok with that.

Comment: Does the provided answer help you out in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare for a broad answer, with many resources to check out.

The issue you are encountering is one that every web *designer* must ask themselves when creating a site. So, the two big goals of good design to keep in mind are:
- *First:* to convey information in a way that is easy for the user to understand,
- *Second:* and convey information in a way that is enjoyable and keeps the user engaged.

There is a time and place for almost every design decision (maybe in scrolling marque, but I'm not convinced of that one yet ;) ). The challenge lies in discovering when it is a good decision to use certain designs. As mentioned in the comments to your question, good design decisions can change based on the style of site you are creating. There is no one catch all design decision, and there is no direct and constant answer to if you should or shouldn't use a border.

*(Note: There are a wide variety of border styles. A border need not just be a simple line, it could even be something like a stark contrast in colors from two backgrounds)*

That being said, here are a few tips to help you ask important questions about whether or not you should use a design element (any element, not just borders).

---

### - Borders help define space

Many times, a single page can contain so much information, or so much content, that is becomes a visual strain to try and distinguish one section of content from another. Let's look at an example of a page that has a significant amount of content on a single page, but uses borders to help separate content appropriately.
Pinterest is a great example of this:
[image: Pinterest Home Page]

On this page we see quite a few borders used, so let's consider possible decisions that were made to use borders. But before we do that, I just want to point out the well formed grid design that is being used here. Using a grid is one of the most important design decisions for web (helpful link: [Grid System](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/all-about-grid-systems--webdesign-14471)), because it helps separate content quite simply. So that's already working in favor of separating content without the need of borders. However, a grid system alone is not enough.

Remember what I said earlier about a border not having to be a line, but rather could be a contrast in color? Well, imagine this Pinterest page without any images, so we just have text. And now imagine that each of those blocks (posts, pins, what have you) has the same background color as the body of the page. We would now have a page with no borders, and you would also have a page that looks cluttered (however, thanks to the grid system, it is still legible):
[image: Borderless Pinterest]

Now this is a doctored example, yes. But it is to show that borders help define space and content so that sections that are supposed to be grouped together are easily differentiable from other content that is close by.

So the action item for this tip is: **Use a border when you need to separate content into logical sections *IF* your design requires content to be separate, *AND* without it the design would appear cluttered.**

Helpful link: [Places Borders Are Used](http://www.bittbox.com/inspiration/32-inspiring-websites-with-borders)

---

### - Borders Complement Content

Borders themselves are not the content the user is trying to look at (unless your site is all about borders...), therefore, your border should not be screaming to the user that it's there. Check out [Gestalt Theory](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/03/28/design-principles-visual-perception-and-the-principles-of-gestalt/), the basis of which is:

> “The whole is other than the sum of the parts.” — Kurt Koffka

Or in other words, the sum of the whole is greater than the sum of the individual parts. That is to say, if you were to look solely at the content, it would not be as good as when you add in the border. And likewise with the border.

What this means leads to is that wild and extravagant borders should not be more wild or extravagant as the content so as to distract us from what we're viewing. This ties back with the first point, that borders are used to define space. They help separate content, they are not the content. *Subtlety is key with borders.*

Action to take from this point: **Don't overpower the content with a border, compliment the content with the border**

---

This is a very boiled down answer to what people go to design school for 4 years to learn, so it is obviously incomplete, and people might have much *much* more to add. But hopefully, this gives you a springboard to what to look for, and what kind of questions to ask yourself when creating a border.

I would encourage you to read up on some design blogs, and see what the trends are for web design in general, because things move so fast in web design.

Here is an article about design choices in web (you might benefit from subscribing to the page): [Symptoms Of An Epidemic: Web Design Trends](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/15/symptoms-of-epidemic-web-design-trends/)

While web design is different from print design, and is moving farther away, don't disregard all print design standards, as many span across the design world. It can be helpful to read up on web design, *as well as print design*.

Hopefully this helps! Feel free to ask for clarification on any point.